# Declaring variable in looped "if" statement

Tags: c++

I'm very new to C++, so apologies for messy code and/or impracticality of question. Basically, I'm trying to write a program that can compare a previously defined variable with a newer version, and I'm going about this my saving the previous integer value as a dummy variable (tv) which I can then compare to the newer version, however this requires taking a the old variable out of the "if" statement and using it in the same function again.

I'm writing this for a ROOT macro, however think it's also a general C++ question, hence me asking here.

In short, is this possible?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int n = 2;

void test1();

void test2(string *q,int *x){
    cout << *q << endl;
    cout << *x << endl;

    if (n==2){
        int tv = *x;
        n++;
        test1();
    }
    if (n>2){
        cout << "testvar = " << tv << endl;
    }
}

void test1(){
    int var = 20;
    string sar = "generic string";
    test2(&sar,&var);
}

int main(){
    test1();
}
```

Any comments are appreciated, and thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the code you show work, and you are just asking about style/architecture, or are you facing some problem with the code? And where is the loop in your code?

Comment: If you want your function to contain state you wither need to use some static variables or make it part of a class.

Comment: Or you can pass in the state as an extra parameter and let the caller keep it.

Comment: It doesn't work, as I haven't figured out a way to "return" (for want of a better word) the variable 'vs' from the first if statement.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I shall do some research - I tried looking at static variables, but it seemed to produce a similar error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
void test2(string *q,int *x){
    static int tv;
    cout << *q << endl;
    cout << *x << endl;

    if (n==2){
        tv = *x;
        n++;
        test1();
    }
    if (n>2){
        cout << "testvar = " << tv << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: you can make `n` static in test2 too.

Comment: Thanks, I tried putting that in, but it still took the value of tv = 0 on the second run of the function?

Comment: Is that a question or a statement?

Comment: Me querying whether I put it in the correct place! In the first part of the test2 function before the if statements, right?

Comment: It has to be before the if because it is used in both if statements. And don't declare it again in the if. int tv = *x;``becomes just tv = *x;` or it will create a second tv variable just for inside the if. It has to be static so it gets remembered across function calls.

Comment: Of course, that makes sense.
That works, thanks for your help!

Comment: Which compiler do you use that warns about a variable with static storage-class being default-initialized? That's perfectly well-defined.

Comment: @Deduplicator My bad, forgot about the default initialization of static. Updated the answer.